# Crash in destructor when using std::enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I am trying to write a boost-signal like class (as practice to learn c++). And I found when I use `enable_shared_from_this`, I always got crash in destructor. Here is the code (I am using vs2012 update 2):

Any comment on this? This issue should be caused `shared_from_this()`, because when I uncomment the line (`auto this_ = shared_from_this();`) in `signal_connection::disconnect`, everything works fine.

I know it must at least has one valid shared_ptr before calling `shared_from_this()`. My code should satisfy this.

**Code**:

```
    #include <memory>
    #include <map>

    class slot_manager;

    class signal_connection: public std::enable_shared_from_this<signal_connection>
    {
    public:
        signal_connection(slot_manager* manager)
            :manager_(manager)
        {}
    public:
        void disconnect() ;
    private:
        slot_manager* manager_;
    };

    class slot_manager
    {
    public:
        typedef std::shared_ptr<signal_connection> connection_type;
        typedef std::map<connection_type, int> map_type;
        typedef map_type::value_type map_value_type;
    public:
        void connect(int slot)
        {
            std::shared_ptr<signal_connection> c(new signal_connection(this));
            slots_.insert(map_value_type(c, slot));
        }
        ~slot_manager()
        {
            auto iter = slots_.begin();
            map_type::iterator iter2 = slots_.end();
            while (iter != slots_.end())
            {
                iter2 = iter++;
                iter2->first->disconnect();
            }
        }
        void disconnect(std::shared_ptr<signal_connection> connection)
        {
            auto c = slots_.find(connection);
            if (c != slots_.end())
            {
                slots_.erase(c);
            }
        }
    protected:
        map_type slots_;
    };

    void signal_connection::disconnect() 
    {
        if (manager_ != nullptr)
        {
            //auto this_ = shared_from_this();
            manager_->disconnect(shared_from_this());
            manager_ = nullptr;
        }
    }

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        slot_manager x;
        x.connect(1);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @KerrekSB: You mean, polite programmers never go naked in public? Only wrapped? :)

Comment: I would prefer `make_shared` to `new`, sure, but that's not the cause of any problem here.

Comment: For what it's worth, valgrind caught this problem right away on Mac OS, even though the program didn't crash.  Use it, love it: valgrind.

Comment: You can simplify your code, remove the ~slot_manager() destructor and add destructor for signal_connection which will only call disconnect() function. Map will automatically free all it's objects ( calling their destructors ).

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Mm, that's right. I'll remove my comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the signal_connection is detroyed in `disconnect()` before you set its manager to `nullptr`, which then causes an access violation, i.e. by the call to the manager's disconnect. This is because the manager holds the only `shared_ptr` to the connection, and you `erase()` that. The object doesn't keep itself alive. Unless, of course, you uncomment that line. `this_` just lives long enough to circumvent the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. My assumption is that the signal_connection should be destroyed after this statement in destructor ' iter2->first->disconnect();', which is wrong based on your comment. Thank you again!